# FastAPI upload file (save it as a name)

Tags: python, api, rest, http, fastapi

I want to know if it's possible with fastAPI, to receive a file and to save it as a name ?
I know that we have to use UploadFile to mention the file we're receiving but how to save it as a special name, like a random string, I don't know.
Thanks for answering and reading !

Comment: Read the file with `await file.read()` and write it to a new file with `open(...) as f` and `f.write()` as you'd write any file in Python. Make sure to write it to a safe path and do not trust the file name given by the client.

Comment: @MatsLindh Is the function write() for saving a file as a name ? I want to save it but also as a name.

Comment: `open(<path>)` is the plain Python function for opening a file. You then write content to that file. The path contains the file name as its last value (i.e. `/path/foo/bar.txt`).

Comment: Can I change the file name? @MatsLindh

Comment: Yes. The file will be written to whatever name you give to the `open` function.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open